# Obtaining highcharts image URL from PHP

Tags: php, json, curl, highcharts

I need to get a highcharts image, and I found a code to resolve my problem, obtaining the name of the image via ajax, and then I paste before the url of the Highcharts API, and I can download the image in PHP, now, I want to do this process in PHP, since the name, until the download; I have this code to get the name of highcharts image:

```
        var optionsStr = JSON.stringify({
  "xAxis": {
    "categories": [
      "PRUEBA",
      "Feb",
      "Mar",
      "Apr",
      "May",
      "Jun",
      "Jul",
      "Aug",
      "Sep",
      "Oct",
      "Nov",
      "Dec"
    ]
  },
  "series": [
    {
      "data": [1, 3, 2, 4],
      "type": "line"
    },
    {
      "data": [5, 3, 4, 2],
      "type": "line"
    }
  ]
}),
        exportUrl ='https://export.highcharts.com/';
        dataString = encodeURI('async=true&type=image/jpeg&width=800&options=' + optionsStr);
            $.ajax(
            {
                type: 'POST',
                data: dataString,
                url: exportUrl,
                success: function(data)
                {
                    console.log('get the file from relative url: ', data);
                    grafica=exportUrl+data;
                },
                error: function(err)
                {
                    console.log('error', err.statusText)
                }
            });
```

I get the name of the graphic: charts/chart.9973ffbcf0d748d6aae04ef6ec01979c.jpeg
I want to know how get the same in PHP, I have this code:

```
$DataEncoded = json_encode(
    array(
    'xAxis'=>
        array(
            'categories'=> ['Ene','Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr']
        ),
    'series'=>
        array(
            array(
                'data'=>[1,2,3,4],
                'type'=>'line'
            ),
            array(
                'data'=>[5,6,7,8],
                'type'=>'line'
            )
        )
    )
);
$DataExtra = 'async=true&type=image/jpeg&width=800&options=';
$dataString = urlencode('async=true&type=image/jpeg&width=800&options='.$DataEncoded);
$url ='https://export.highcharts.com/';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
$json=curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_errno($ch)){
    echo "Entro al curl Error";
    throw new Exception(curl_error($ch));
}
var_dump(json_decode($json));
curl_close($ch);
```

But I receive a fantastic: NULL. Someone made this before?
I tried making this process via Angular 5, but, I must to program a cron job to delegate the process, so, I decided to use PHP. I tried with file_get_contents() but the webservice give me: **"No data chart found".**

Comment: Try leaving off the Content-Type header (you're not posting raw JSON, you just happen to be including it in one of the parameters).  If that alone doesn't fix it, I'd also try leaving off the `urlencode()`, as that should be taken care of automatically.

Comment: Based on your post, it sounds like you never got the AJAX to work, and then you switched to PHP/Curl, and that didn't work either. Is that correct?

Comment: It Works in Ajax, I get the name of the image, then I paste: export.highcharts.com/chart/blablablabla.jpg and I download the image with PHP. But I need to replace Ajax code with PHP code. That's my problem. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your issue is here:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataString);
```

I believe this is expecting a String or an Array.

> This parameter can either be passed as a urlencoded string like 'para1=val1&para2=val2&...' or as an array with the field name as key and field data as value. If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files are passed to this option with the @ prefix. As of PHP 5.5.0, the @ prefix is deprecated and files can be sent using CURLFile.

Consider trying the following:

```
$dataArray = array(
  "async" => true,
  "type" => "image/jpeg",
  "width" => 800,
  "options" => $DataEncoded
);
```

And...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $dataArray);
```

Credit to @[Patrick Q](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505169/patrick-q) for catching the Encoding Type. You're not exactly sending it JSON encoded data, but Form data essentially.

Comment: @MartinRafaelPérezLara thats good news! I'm glad this helped. If it answers your questions, I hope you will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I used the recommendations of Twisty and finally I obtain the name of the image, thank you so much.

```
$dataString = ('async=true&type=image/jpeg&width=800&options='.$DataEncoded);
$url ='https://export.highcharts.com/?';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$dataString);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/json";
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```